# Change Rectangle Height with Button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a rectangle and a button. When the user clicks the button, I want the rectangle to get bigger. This is my code:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.stroke();

var height = 150;

function myFunction(){
 height = 300;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="height" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Although, nothing happens when I click the button. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height="height"` is not a valid value in html.

On click of button you can change the `style.height` of the canvas

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.stroke();

var height = 150;

function myFunction(){
    c.style.height = '300px'; // changed here
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/awqj0s8h/3/)

Edit

Remove the `width` from the html, add it through css

**JS**

```
 function myFunction(){
        c.style.height ='300px';
    }
```

**CSS**

```
 #myCanvas{
    width:300px
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"  style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/awqj0s8h/5/)

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.stroke();



function myFunction(){
 c.style.height ='300px';
}
```

```css
#myCanvas{
width:300px
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<canvas id="myCanvas"  style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why does it increase the width too? I don't want to increase the width.

Comment: Can you make it keep the line thickness? Sorry for being so picky.

Comment: what is line thickness

Comment: I don't know. Instead of putting the thickness, just put a question mark where the thickness would be and I can find the thickness